# Clipping vector polygons by previous vector polygons in same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

I have extremely large datasets as vector polygons in single layers.  The polygons are in an order.  I want the previous ordered polygons to clip the later polygons.  Therefore, once an area has been used it can't get used again.

Example:

1. polygon 1 would never be clipped
2. polygon 2 would be clipped by polygon 1
3. polygon 3 would be clipped by polygon 1 & 2
4. polygon 4 would be clipped by polygon 1 - 3
   ...
5. polygon 5000 would be clipped by polygon 1 - 4999 if no unused space
   is left for polygon 5000 or any other polygon it gets eliminated.